# Facebook Like Box for my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I am trying to implement `facebook like box` for my `facebook page` on `my own site`. I copied the code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ (HTML5 or any other) and pasted on my site. Box appears with all the correct information bu when I click on like, I get an error message saying

"The page at http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx/111111 could not be reached."

I've been trying to find a solution for this for hours but couldn't find anything. It's nothing to do with the privileges etc.

I also ran it through Object Debugger and it didn't come up with any problem.

Does anyone has any solution for this? I created the page today, does facebook needs time to parse/index my page before like box works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all of a sudden it started working. Haven't changed anything in the code. So I guess Like Box won't work if you install it on the same day you create the FB Page.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any demographic restrictions on your page that would prevent it being seen by somebody logged out of Facebook? Is it the published? Those are the two most common reasons for that error that I've seen

Comment: Both are set correctly. Anybody +13 and country field is empty and it's published

Comment: And, silly question, it's definitely a Like Box and not a comments plugin or Like Button?

Comment: Definitely like box. See the url in my question